# SpringBoot GetMapping as Json format

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

I would like to be able to pass my parameters in Json format via Postman, but I can't manage it. The query only works in raw text format. How can I change this?

```
@SpringBootApplication
class JwtTokenApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 runApplication<JwtTokenApplication>(*args)
}
```

UserRepository:

```
interface UserRepository: MongoRepository<User,String>{

fun findByEmail(email: String): User?

}
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
class UserController(@Autowired private val userRepository: UserRepository) {

...

@GetMapping("/email")
fun findByUserEmail(@RequestBody email:String):User? = userRepository.findByEmail(email)

}
```

Comment: You mean the RequestBody in your /email endpoint ? You asked for a String as input, so it can't be a json. Change to a real POJO then you can have a json input. BTW never ask for a body on a GET endpoint. It is a very bad API design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise against using `@RequestBody` on an Get-Request as it is allowed, but not usual. Also you are passing just one String-parameter `email`, what is imo not enough to justify object deserialization.

My rule of thumb here is: mandatory parameters are `@PathParameter` and optional parameters are `@RequestParam`. This is espacially helpful if you want to generate links, as you cannot represent a requestbody in a Link.